# Partial sum of squared binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Is there any formula for the partial sum of squared binomial coefficients
$$S_n(k):= \sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{n}{i}^2,$$
where $k<n$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not even the partial sum of binomial coefficients has a closed form, let alone the partial sum of *squared* binomial coefficients.

Comment: According to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialSums.html , you have $$S_n(n) = {2n \choose n}$$

Comment: I'd even appreciate nontrivial bounds.